# GoDadddy Disk Space Usage figure doesn't make sense

Tags: godaddy, linux

I'm trying to figure out how much disk space my website takes up. I'mm looking on cPanel (Linux version) and the Disk Space Usage figure doesn't make sense:

[image]

Maybe i'm just being stupid but they haven't specified the unit type. Am I really using up 70.99GB of disk space? Isn't the green bar supposed to fill up?

Probably a stupid question, but it's not very clear!

Comment: you should ask that question on their support system

Comment: GoDaddy doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably mean 70.99MB / 100GB.